# How do I play a gif in godot4?

Tags: gif, gdscript, godot4

I want to play a simple gif in my godot4 project.

Let's say that I have a gif file named video.gif. How do I play it using GDscript? Which component would play a gif? If I can't play a gif, can I play a video file? If I also can't do that, how can I display a video/gif in godot4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box Godot does not have support for gif. *It might be possible to add this functionality via plugins, however I'm not aware of one for gif.*

If you can use video, then I recommend the OGV format, which Godot supports, of course. You can play it with the [`VideoStreamPlayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_videostreamplayer.html) in Godot 4, or the [`VideoPlayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_videoplayer.html#videoplayer) in Godot 3. *Godot 3 also had support for WEBM video, however it was problematic, which let to it being removed for Godot 4.*

See Playing Videos ([Godot 4](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/animation/playing_videos.html), [Godot 3](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/animation/playing_videos.html)) for details.